# How to refer to object above from a property function

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I would like to define a function (f) as a property of an object (o).
In this function, I would like to refer to a property of not the function (f) but the object above (o).
In this case, I cannot use `this`, since it refers to the function (f).

```
var o = {
   t : 0,
   f : new function(){ 
      return this.t;
   }
}
```

As it is logical, `this` in this snippet tries to get the t property of the function (f).
How can I access o.t now?

**UPDATE:**

This snippet:

```
var o = {
   t : 0,
   f : new function(){ 
      return o.t;
   }
}
```

is working neither ( logically ), since the object (o) is not yet defined at the time of the declaration of this property (f)

Comment: In a function  called with [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), `this` will refer to the newly created object. Also constructor functions should not return anything, or if they do, return value should be an object.

Comment: Is it because JS is "instance-sensitive"? Why does `function()` itself not create a new instance?

Comment: Because it's a function, not an object. Calling any function with `new` returns an instance from that function. Basicly `this.t` is not defined within anonymous function, hence the return value is ignored, and only `this` is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the word `new`:

```
var o = {
  t : 0,
  f : function() {
    return this.t;
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K28Hj/)

Comment: Could You, please, extend Your answer with a bit of explanation about it is, or it is not possible to refer above in some way, if I decide to use new instance of a function (f) using `new` ?

Comment: Teemu's comment above answers that better than I could have.